# Scrolling through page in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll, scrolltop

Can you please explain/break-down the following syntax on how 'scrollTop' works in Selenium-Python:

```
inner_window = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + 
document.getElementById("ID").scrollHeight;',
inner_window,)
```

Above code scrolls down directly to the bottom of the scroll bar and picks the values at the bottom, whereas I need to scroll through and pick values from top, middle and bottom of the page.

Also, how would I know when the bottom of the scroll is reached??

I also tried the below, but didn't work:

```
ht= driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('ID').scrollHeight")
print(ht)
nht= ht//3
print(nht)
sht = str(nht)



inner_window = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")


for items in ree:
    time.sleep(1)
    wer=items.text.replace(' ','')
    #print(wer)
    arr1.append(wer)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + '+sht+';',
    inner_window,
    )


time.sleep(10)

print(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the end of an page with Selenium, the safest way isn't to use JavaScript, but to simulate pressing the End key:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

body_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")
body_element.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

But there's an even easier way. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

[Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) has several options for scrolling, just a few lines of code is needed. Examples:

```py
from browserist import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.open.url("https://stackoverflow.com")
browser.scroll.into_view("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[6]")
browser.scroll.page.to_end()
browser.scroll.page.to_top()
browser.scroll.page.down()
browser.scroll.down_by(100)
browser.scroll.up_by(50)
```

Here's what I get (slowed down as [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) finishes the job quickly). I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Example of scrolling with Browserist]